# Assigning cells in R dataframe average value by value in different column

Tags: r, dataframe, average

I have a very large dataframe, part of which looks like this:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 7 |

I know all rows with the same value in col1 should have the same value in col2, and any deviation is due to measuring uncertainty. I want to assign the cells in col2 the average value for all col2 cells in rows with the same col1 value, resulting in something like this:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3.5 |
| A | 3.5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 6 |

The real dataset is too large to do this manually for each individual unique col1 value. Does anyone have any idea on how to automate this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by()` and `mutate()` from the `tidyverse` package to achieve this. First you group for `col1` and then you use `mutate()` to write the means into `col2`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
col1 <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
col2 <- c(3,4,5,7)

df <- data.frame(col1, col2)

df %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  mutate(col2 = mean(col2))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#> # Groups:   col1 [2]
#>   col1   col2
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A       3.5
#> 2 A       3.5
#> 3 B       6  
#> 4 B       6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>